# numba jit usage does not show on windows task manager

Tags: python, numba, taskmanager

```
import math
import numba as nb
from numba import jit
x = 1
a = 1
b = 1
y = 0
n = 1000

@jit(nopython=True)
def f(n,x,a,b,y):
    while x < n:
        while a < n:
            while b < n:
                if a>x and b>x:
                    y = math.sqrt(int((a*a)+(b*b)-(x*x)))
                    if y**2-x**2>a**3:
                        return 0
                b+=1
            b=1
            a+=1
       a=1
       x+=1
print(f(n,x,a,b,y))
```

I was trying to test this code running in gpu but task manager showing 0% GPU usage, I am not sure if numba can run loops or what the alternatives would be.

Comment: Well... yeah. `numba.jit` doesn't make stuff run on GPUs.

Comment: That `f` doesn't make sense anyway, GPU or not. It ignores the `y` argument, and the truth values of the loop conditions never change.